# filtering cases with NAs on two columns by group

Tags: r, dplyr

```
df <- data.frame(x=c("s1","s1","s1","s1","s2","s2","s2","s2","s3","s3","s3","s3"), y=c("g1","g2","g3","g4","g1","g2","g3","g4","g1","g2","g3","g4"), z1=c(1,2,3,2,4,5,6,6,3,2,4,NA), z2=c(NA,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,1,2,1,NA))
```

I'd like to select only those groups that do not contain NAs. I thought this would work:

```
columns <- c("z1", "z2")
df %>% group_by(x) %>% filter(all(!is.na(!!columns)))
```

but it doesn't seem to be filtering

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to use `across`:

```r
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)

columns <- c("z1", "z2")

df %>%
  group_by(x) %>%
  filter(all(across(all_of(columns), ~ !is.na(.x))))

#> # A tibble: 4 × 4
#> # Groups:   x [1]
#>   x     y        z1    z2
#>   <chr> <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 s2    g1        4     1
#> 2 s2    g2        5     2
#> 3 s2    g3        6     3
#> 4 s2    g4        6     1
```

Comment: thanks, it works great! Yes, I meant z1 and z2, I already fixed the question.

Answer (score 2):

An approach using `if_all` within `filter` with *columns*

```
library(dplyr)

columns <- c("z1", "z2")

df %>% 
  group_by(x) %>% 
  filter(if_all(!!columns, ~ all(!is.na(.x))))
# A tibble: 4 × 4
# Groups:   x [1]
  x     y        z1    z2
  <chr> <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1 s2    g1        4     1
2 s2    g2        5     2
3 s2    g3        6     3
4 s2    g4        6     1
```

or using *tidyselect* `matches`

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(x) %>% 
  filter(if_all(matches("z[12]"), ~ all(!is.na(.x))))
# A tibble: 4 × 4
# Groups:   x [1]
  x     y        z1    z2
  <chr> <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1 s2    g1        4     1
2 s2    g2        5     2
3 s2    g3        6     3
4 s2    g4        6     1
```

Answer (score 0):

use sjmisc package

```
library(sjmisc)
df %>% group_by(x) %>% row_count(., count = NA) %>% #count NA in each row
add_count(wt=rowcount) %>% #sum for each group
filter(n==0)  #filter out groups with NA
```

Answer (score 0):

**data.table**

```r
library(data.table)

df <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
  x = c("s1","s1","s1","s1","s2", "s2","s2","s2","s3","s3","s3","s3"),
  y = c("g1","g2","g3","g4","g1", "g2","g3","g4","g1","g2","g3","g4"),
  z1 = c(1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 5, 6, 6, 3, 2, 4, NA),
  z2 = c(NA, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, NA)
)


setDT(df)[, .SD[all(!is.na(rowSums(.SD)))], .SDcols = is.numeric, by = x] 
#>     x z1 z2
#> 1: s2  4  1
#> 2: s2  5  2
#> 3: s2  6  3
#> 4: s2  6  1
```

<sup>Created on 2023-05-11 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>